# Call bloc event on screen load

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have my detail screen which appears after login. I have set up bloc for my main page as follows:

```
`@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<LoginBloc>(
        create: (context) => locator<LoginBloc>(),
        child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          onGenerateRoute: AppRoutes.onGeneratedRoutes,
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: getTheme(),
          home: const Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            body: SafeArea(
              child: LoginPage(),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }`
```

After login completion user is on Home screen. Now I need to call an api on page load and update some content based upon the result.
I am trying to use it in the Home screen as following:

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String dropdownValue = 'list.first';
    final _taxIdentificationController = TextEditingController();
    return BlocListener<TaxDetailBloc, TaxDetailState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        // listen to SubmitFieldBloc
      },
      child: BlocBuilder<TaxDetailBloc, TaxDetailState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            return TaxDetailUI();
          }
      ),
    );
  }
```

I am not sure how do I call the OnTaxDetailsRequestedEvent() from here in the code. I am not really updating anything in the TaxDetailUI()

Answer (score 0):

You can call the event like this:

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  final bloc = context.read<TaxDetailBloc>();
  bloc.add(OnTaxDetailsRequestedEvent());

  return TaxDetailUI();
}
```

This is the reference of read from the docs:

> [ReadContext] and its
> read method, similar to [watch], but doesn't make widgets rebuild if
> the value obtained changes.

It's usually used to call events from the bloc because you don't need to rebuild the widget

Comment: When I try this I get Error: Could not find the correct Provider<TaxDetailBloc> above this TaxDetailPage Widget

Comment: Make sure you have created the BlocProvider<TaxDetailBloc> (create: ... on a parent widget. Or use MultiBlocProvider to create it at the same level as your LoginBloc